# Semantic UI - Search API: how I can highlight certain characters that match the query?

Tags: javascript, jquery, semantic-ui

I have a problem when I want to ***highlight*** certain characters that match the query in [search module](http://semantic-ui.com/modules/search.html).

an example is like this forum: https://forums.meteor.com

[image: highlight]

> Previously, I already asked this issue at https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/issues/4930#issuecomment-275011130, but until now not been resolved.

here is my current demo: https://jsfiddle.net/agaust/5854gae9/4/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.fn.api.settings.api = {
    'search': 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/agusmakmun/e258a3243367105c32919c083eb577fe/raw/8b0038b0141f5813c03baece0b2730e17216f8c9/result-data.json?q={query}'
  };

  $('.ui.search.quick-search').search({
    type          : 'category',
    minCharacters : 1, // just under devel to make it easy
    apiSettings   : {
      action: 'search',
      onResponse: function(searchApiResponse) {
        var response = {
          results : {},
          //action  : searchApiResponse.action // dict action
        };
        // translate `searchApiResponse` response to work with search
        var numbThreads = 0, numbUsers = 0;
        $.each(searchApiResponse.items, function(index, item) {
          var
            model = item.model || 'Unknown',
            maxResults = 6,
            maxItems = maxResults/2 // max results per-Category
          ;
          if(index >= maxResults) {
            return false;
          }
          // create new model category
          if(response.results[model] === undefined) {
            response.results[model] = {
              name    : model,
              results : []
            };
          }
          if(item.model === 'Threads') {
            if ((numbThreads < maxItems) || (numbUsers < numbThreads)) {
              response.results[model].results.push({
                title: item.title,
                description: item.description,
                url: item.url
              });
            }
            numbThreads++;
          }else if (item.model === 'Users') {
            if ((numbUsers < maxItems) || (numbThreads < numbUsers)) {
              response.results[model].results.push({
                title: item.username,
                description: item.username,
                url: item.profile_url,
                image: item.gravatar_url,
                price: item.total_threads
              });
            }
            numbUsers++;
          }
        });

        // only showing the bottom action button if under limited
        if (searchApiResponse.limited_items) {
          response["action"] = searchApiResponse.action;
        }
        console.log(response);
        return response;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

any help would be apreciated.. :)

Comment: I think on item.description you should replace with a regex and wrap it with <strong></strong> usually I do it from the backend, but in this case this is the only way I think.

Comment: does it supported with html syntax?

Comment: omg, it works perfectly... I never think it before... thank you so much @peterpeterson